# Set up keepalived for MySQL Master-Master replication

Tags: linux, mysql, replication, keepalived

I managed 2 mysqld processes that listen for connections on different ports- 3306 and 3307 on localhost. I set up MySQL Master-Master replication. And now I want to set up keepalived for MySQL Master-Master with virtual IP. Is it real to set up keepalived on localhost for different ports?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you are doing this as a testing purpose? I don't see any advantage doing this on the same host at all.

I advise you to let go keepalived and use Corosync/Pacemaker. This is more reliable for HA. Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! You are right it's only for testing. But is it possible to set up keepalived for two mysqld on one host?

Comment: I don't think you need keepalived per say. Keepalived is the system that control nodes. Who is available and who's not. Then it decide where to put the IP so the service will always be available.

Comment: You need something like lvs. I'm not sure that this is the best website to set ip up but it's a start for you: http://kaivanov.blogspot.ca/2013/01/building-load-balancer-with-lvs-linux.html

So if you want something more stable:
Keepalive is the equivalent of Corosync and LVS is the equivalent of Pacemaker. Corosync/pacemaker is so much reliable.